# How to add paypal pay button

Tags: paypal, invoices

I browsed the paypal documentation but cant find an example on how to simply add a paypal pay button.

We have invoices in our system and like to provide a pay via paypal option. I would expect that there is a method available to do exactly that. Not having to create a paypal invoice or via a cart which the documentation seem to suggest.

Just a method to initiate a payment via

- a simple button/link via http get; or
- a form using a http post

Both accepting somewhat :

- the merchant code,
- a (unique) payment identification that we created,
- the amount
- the currency,
- a http callback so we know a payment has been completed/cancelled with the given unique identification

I just need to find the documentation page to make this possible.

It seems that paypal does not provide a pay button (anymore?) so we have to create our own.

Comment: May be you are looking for this? https://developer.paypal.com/docs/

Comment: That is the default documentation page. I cant find it there.

Comment: Seems that the following link is what Im searching but I don't see how to specify a unique identification and a callback url.

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_techview_outside

Comment: Did you try submitting the form? I guess the callback url will be captured by Paypal and once payment is done, PayPal would redirect it through. Just guessing here.

Comment: I'm currently using the following information and added the tax argument. No callback yet but this will be good enough for now.

http://runtingsproper.blogspot.nl/2009/07/simple-paypal-button.html